# Identify DIV without changing ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I downloaded a web admin template with has a lot of HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

I am doing a JSP application and make a for statement, where the "delete" button opens a Modal which I copy pasted from the template

```
<% for(Group g:(List<Group>)request.getAttribute("data")){ %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%=g.getName()%>
        </td>
        <td>    <a href="ControladorGroups?action=edit&id=<%=g.getId()%>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>

            <div class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="sd"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </div>
        </td>
        <div id="uidemo-modals-alerts-danger" class="modal modal-alert modal-danger fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">  <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-title">Are you sure?</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">  <a href="ControladorGroups?action=delete&id=<%=g.getId()%>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button></a>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / .modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- / .modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- / .modal -->
    </tr>
    <%} %>
```

The thing is that when the "Yes" of the modal is clicked it always shows `id`=1, because the div is repeated and the "Delete" button always go to the first div appearence.

How can I make the modal get the `id` without touching the CSS and JavaScript because this modal id has much javascript and css code related, and i dont want to change it because of feature template updates, and also i dont know how many divs im going to print

Comment: What does the ID have to do with CSS? They need to be unique so I think you should change that.

Comment: Because i dont want to change the CSS because of future template updates, and seems than much of the css and javascript is related to that id.

Comment: is it possible to have only the HTML code generated from your script to check out IDs values and structure ? the best is a jsfiddle or codepen showing clearly your issue :)

Comment: i cant, have to import the css and js they are in many files :s, anyway, seems pretty logic which is the outcome. The modal div is repeated with same id